# In a substance do atoms actually touch each other?

Tags: electrons

In a substance do atoms actually touch each other?

Comment: The problem here is that you're using your macroscopic intuition of the concept of "touch" and applying that to a microscopic system.

Comment: That is terrible reasoning and I wonder how it got even single upvote. There's no fixed orbits and "touching electrons" are even worse.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum mechanics fuzzes out the electrons into clouds of probability distribution (the motion of little electrons orbiting the nucleus is from an old outdated model).  In molecules these electronic clouds do not so much touch, rather they overlap.  See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond.

Answer (score -1):

Your question contains a number of conceptual errors that make it clear you have not covered quantum mechanics in any form in your classes yet.

Traditionally, because that was their experience in the real world, scientists would indeed think of atoms as compact spheres (Dalton), hollow spheres with a nucleus and electrons revolving (Rutherford) or the same type of hollow sphere with a nucleus but different orbits on which electrons can be located (Bohr). Using real-world examples, the Dalton model is basically a marble, the Rutherford model a type of cherry and the Bohr model like the solar system.

In all of these models, an atom would have a defined outer boundary which would mark the end and electrons were thought not to go past this boundary except in a reaction. However, these models pose a number of problems that could not be explained using traditional mechanics. For example, an electron revolving around a nucleus would constantly be accelerated towards the nucleus and therefore would [emit electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonradiation_condition) according to classical physics. This is not observed for atoms. Since there was no way to reconcile the atomic models of Rutherford and Bohr with classical mechanics, an entirely new way to think of atoms needed to be discovered.

This is where quantum mechanics come in. Using the wave-particle dualism and a set of axioms, wave functions for electrons can be calculated. These wave functions give rise to a certain energy (and also to some other observables) that can be measured and that explains the energy levels Bohr had in mind when devising his atomic model very well. Another consequence of this wave function model is that **it no longer makes sense to imagine a fixed atom boundary.** Theoretically, an electron of an atom can be infinitely far away from the nucleus while still belonging to it. (In mathematical terms: even for very large distances $r$ the absolute value of the wave function $\Phi\ne0$.)

This means that your notion of atoms ‘touching’ does not make sense at microscopic levels, since there is no boundary that could be touching the other side. Instead, the nuclei will come close enough to each other so that the electrons can interact in a favourable way while just far enough apart so that their electrostatic interaction does not dominate.